# How to convert default mysql modtimes into UTC date time using xslt

Tags: mysql, xml, xslt, xpath

I need to convert default mysql modtimes into UTC formated datetimes using xslt.

I have an xml document that contains dates that originated as mysql modtimes in the format:
2010-06-30 15:20:43.0

They are now in an xml document within an element "datestamp"
2010-03-16 13:52:56.0

In order to be published via an oai-pmh feed they need to be converted to UTC format:
2010-06-30T15:20:43Z

ISO 8601 UTC dates are defined here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

I don't have access to the original mysql database, only an xml dump.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a simple XSLT (and one-liner XPath) solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(
           translate(substring-before(.,'.'),
                     ' ',
                     'T'
                     ),
            'Z'
            )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<oai:datestamp xmlns:oai="some:ns">2010-03-16 13:52:56.0</oai:datestamp>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<oai:datestamp xmlns:oai="some:ns">2010-03-16T13:52:56Z</oai:datestamp>
```

**Do note**: The value is transformed into the wanted format using a single XPath expression, this is why I added the tag `xpath`.